# Update an array with fields from matching array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have Array1 that pulls all of the entries for a Wordpress custom post type, and I have Array2 from another table that shows if that post type has been seen by a specific user. If the ID of Array1 & the PageID of Array2 are the same, then add the [Started] & [Finished] fields from Array2 to Array1.  Basically I want to combine them to form Array3.  I have tried many different solutions with array_combine but can't get the result I'm looking for.

```
Array1 ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 75 [post_title] => Test Training Video ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 80 [post_title] => Test 2 )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 85 [post_title] => Test 2 ) ) 

Array2 ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [PageID] => 75 [Started] => 1 [Finished] => 1 )
[0] => stdClass Object ( [PageID] => 80 [Started] => 1 [Finished] => 0 ) )

Array3 ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 75 [post_title] => Test Training Video [Started] => 1 [Finished] => 1 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 80 [post_title] => Test 2 [Started] => 1 [Finished] => 0 )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 85 [post_title] => Test 2 ) )
```

Comment: Include your attempts in the question and also any errors that came from those attempts.

Comment: Is it possible to do on SQL level with JOIN rather that merging arrays? It could be a better solution.

Comment: Stepashka, in most cases join will be a bad thing for wordpress and there is no perfect solution:)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$array3 = array();
foreach( $array1 as $arr1 )
{
   foreach( $array2 as $arr2 )
   {
      if( $arr1["ID"] == $arr2["PageID"] )
      {
         $array3[] = array( $arr1["Started"], $arr2["Finished"] );
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: There are not many other solutions.
The only other way would be to remap the "PageID" keys to "ID" via an array_map call and the use array_merge_recursive() on the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is not the right function for this.

In your case, you need to use a foreach-loop to loop over the values of your first array and compare them with your second array.

You also need to rearrange array 2, so that you can easily access the values for `started` and `finished` using the pageID as key:

```
$pageMap = array();
foreach($array2 as $entry) {
    $pageMap[$entry['PageID']] = array('started' => $entry['Started'], 'finished' => $entry['Finished']);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$combined_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $post) {
    if(!isset($pageMap[$post['ID']])) continue; // do nothing if there are no started/finished entries.
    $combined_array[$post['ID']] = array_merge($post, $pageMap[$post['ID']]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a first loop to make your array "ID" match and then combine both arrays

```
foreach( $array2 as $key=>$value )
   {
      $value['ID'] = $value['PageId'];
      unset($value['PageId']);
      $array2[$key] = $value;
   }

$array3 = array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
```

Comment: You could avoid the foreach() loop if you can use an SQL ALIAS  on any of the two queries to make sure the "ID" key is the same on both side and then only use the array_merge_recursive

Answer (score 0):

After trying the posted solutions I decided to make the change in my $wpdb->get_results sql statement instead of using 2 different sql statements and then combining the 2 different arrays.  With help from this post - [SQL query to join two tables despite the other table may not have values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403978/sql-query-to-join-two-tables-despite-the-other-table-may-not-have-values), I was able to use the following to get the desired result.

```
   $oneBigQuery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, b.PageID, b.Started, b.Finished
FROM $wpdb->posts AS a
LEFT JOIN exampleTableName AS b
    ON a.ID = b.PageID
    AND b.UserID = 3
WHERE a.post_type = 'custom-post-type'
    ");
```